# Por que essa consulta retorna *?

Tags: sql

Por que essa consulta me retorna `*`?

```
select convert(varchar(2), 141)
```

Pensei que fosse a tabela ascii, porém o 141, não corresponde ao *.

Utilizo `SQL Server 2008 R2`

Comment: Qual é o banco que tu está usando?

Comment: Acho que depende do COLLATE. O * pode ser porque não tem um caractere válido para imprimir.

Comment: @JéfersonTavares SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando inteiros são convertidos implicitamente para um tipo de dados de caracteres, se o número inteiro for muito grande para caber no campo de caracteres, o SQL Server retorna o caractere 42 da Tabela ASCII, o asterisco (*).

Logo qualquer número com o tamanho maior que 2 caracteres irá retornar `*`. Caso você queira exibir o 141 é só aumentar a quantidade de caracteres:

```
select convert(varchar(3), 141)
```

Retorno: 141.

**Fonte:** [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)